# How can I query MongoDB based on Carbon dates?

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel, datetime, php-carbon

Here's a snippet of code that I would expect would return one result:

```
    $today = new Carbon();
    $newUser = new User();
    $newUser->yesterday = $today->subDay();
    $newUser->save();

    $matches = User::where('yesterday', '<', $today)->get();



    return $matches;
```

And yet I get an empty array. Can someone help me identify the problem here?

I do believe it has to do with the way that I'm saving the `yesterday` property. If it were an ISODate, this query would work properly. Maybe I'm missing something obvious in converting Carbon objects to ISODates...

Any help appreciated.

Comment: `I do believe it has to do with the way that I'm saving the yesterday property`. Then you will need to show us that.

Comment: Can you show what do you have here - `$newUser->yesterday` ?

Comment: It saves as a Carbon object (3 key values). `{
        "date" : "2018-06-05 21:07:57.000000",
        "timezone_type" : NumberLong(3),
        "timezone" : "UTC"
    },`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using the dates property on the appropriate laravel model (which works extremely well with carbon)

```
class User extends Model
{
    protected $dates = ['yesterday'];

    public function yourfunction(){

    }
}
```

The laravel docs has a good guide on how to use the dates property [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators)

Comment: This was exactly what I needed!! Cheers.